# Convert rewrite rules to nginx conf for typo3

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I have the followin rewrite rules. They are needed to get CoolURI for typo3 working on an apache server. Now I want to do the same for nginx server.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/(typo3|typo3temp|typo3conf|t3lib|tslib|fileadmin|uploads|showpic\.php)$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^/(typo3|typo3temp|typo3conf|t3lib|tslib|fileadmin|uploads|showpic\.php)/.*$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php
```

Can anyone help me to convert those to nginx conf? I  found this http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html but I am really new to nginx and cannot figure out how to convert this...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
location / {
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri @rewrite;
}

location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/(typo3|typo3temp|typo3conf|t3lib|tslib|fileadmin|uploads|showpic\.php)$ - last;
    rewrite ^/(typo3|typo3temp|typo3conf|t3lib|tslib|fileadmin|uploads|showpic\.php)/.*$ - last;
}
```

You would put this within the `server { ... }` declaration.

I don't use Typo3, so I can't say for certain if it WILL work, but it may just need some basic tweaking.

Comment: Isn't here the final `RewriteRule .* index.php` missing?

Comment: @MichaelHärtl You don't need to rewrite to index.php with the way the `location / {...}` block is written.

Comment: Sorry, but i think you're wrong. I tried and it didn't work for me. Below the last `rewrite` inside the `location @rewrite` i had to add `try_files $uri /index.php;` to make it work.

Comment: Fair enough. I never actually tested it because I don't run Typo3.